# Let $f: R \to R$ be a differentiable function having $f(2) =6, f'(2) =(\frac{1}{48})$. Find $\lim_{x\to 2} \int^{f(x)}_6 \frac{4t^3}{x-2} \, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(2) =6, f'(2) =(\frac{1}{48})$. Find $\lim_{x\to 2} \int^{f(x)}_6 \frac{4t^3}{x-2}\,dt$.

Please suggest how to proceed in such questions... will be of great help.. thanks.

Comment: Solve the integral first. The end result is $18$.

Comment: In this case it's easy to evaluate the integral and go on from there. But there's also a way to do this in cases where you can't do that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\int _6^{f(x)}4t^3 =(f(x))^4-6^4$$

Thus $$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac {1}{x-2} \int _6^{f(x)}4t^3=$$

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac {(f(x))^4-6^4}{x-2} $$

Therefore,  $$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac {(f(x))^4-6^4}{x-2}= 4(f(x))^3(f'(x))=18$$

Comment: Why use L'Hopital's rule when this is just an instance of the definition of differentiation, and you can cite that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are correct, there is no need for L'Hospital rule.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Check the edit please.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could do L'Hopital rule first and avoid integration altogether:

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\int_6^{f(x)} 4t^3 dt}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{4(f(x))^3f'(x)}{1} = 18$$

This approach is more useful since it allows us to compute the limit even if the integral is not doable by hand, or could save time computing a nasty integral.

Comment: This is an instance of the phenomenon by which L'Hopital's rule efficiently gives answers without helping understanding.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Could you clarify? I'm not aware of any instance of L'Hopital problem solving that lends itself to understanding over being a computational tool for professors who like to write complicated exam questions. Not to mention, this approach is conceptually rewarding because it requires an understanding of the fundamental theorem of calculus, which in my experience is the goal of these types of questions.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I read your comment on the other post and see what you mean. We come from two different perspectives, as I am used to preparing students for much more complicated denominators. I agree, a defintion of derivative answer would be the nicest use here. But I stand by my intent of potentially preparing for more complicated problems that cannot be solved in "cute" ways.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
\int^{f(x)}_6 4t^3\cdot\frac 1 {x-2} \, dt. \tag 1
$$
First note that as $t$ goes from $6$ to $f(x),$ the factor $\dfrac 1 {x-2}$ does not change. Therefore $(1)$ is equal to
$$
\left(\int_6^{f(x)} 4t^3 \, dt\right) \cdot \frac 1 {x-2}, \tag 2
$$
i.e. the factor $\dfrac 1 {x-2}$ is entirely outside of the integral. In this case you *could* easily evaluate the integral, but you don't actually need that.

Observe that $(2)$ is equal to
$$
\int_{f(2)}^{f(x)} 4t^2\,dt \cdot \frac 1 {x-2}. \tag 3
$$

Let $\displaystyle g(x) = \int_{f(2)}^{f(x)} 4t^3\,dt.$ Then $(3)$ becomes
$$
\big( g(x) - g(2)\big) \cdot \frac 1 {x-2}
$$
or
$$
\frac{g(x)-g(2)}{x-2}.
$$
The definition of differentiation then tells us that
$$
\lim_{x\to2} \frac{g(x)-g(2)}{x-2} = g'(2).
$$
So we're looking for $g'(2).$

We have
$$
y = g(x) = \int_6^u 4t^3\cdot dt \quad \text{and } u = f(x).
$$
So
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx} = 4u^3\cdot f'(x).
$$
Now plug in $x=2,$ which makes $u=6.$